# If condition does not work / not running

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongojs

I'm trying to match mongodb object id with `if` condition:

```
if (reply[i].data[j].ref == item._id) console.log('match!!!')
```

The sample of reply & item:

```
// REPLY
[{
   "_id":10,
    "data":  [
      {
        "_id":"57f485203858fe43b464ae52",
        "type":"product",
        "ref":"57f485473858fe43b464ae56",
        "name":"KARUNG",
        "direction":"in",
        "supplier":null,
        "information":"PENYESUAIAN JUMLAH",
        "qty":200,
        "manifest":null,
        "timestamp":"2016-10-05T04:44:16.354Z",
        "saldo":1200
      }
    ]
 }]

// ITEM
{
    "_id" : "57f485473858fe43b464ae56",
    "name" : "BERAS KC",
    "unit" : "SAK",
    "qty" : 213,
    "weight" : 10
}
```

I was also trying to convert both to ObjectId using mongojs.ObjectId, but it doesn't work.

The full code snippet: http://pastebin.com/SYTLVWqT

Comment: do you get any error in console ?

Comment: i was hoping to get an error, but no it just blank

Comment: What do you get on line 27 of your full snippet? `console.log("!ObjectId: reply: ", reply[i].data[j].ref, ",item: ", item._id);`

Comment: @plastikbaum here's the one that match
 `!ObjectId: reply:  57f485473858fe43b464ae56 , item:  57f485473858fe43b464ae56`

Comment: Is there a space after the id `reply:  57f485473858fe43b464ae56[HERE]`? Don't see it in the source. Because there's nothing wrong with your code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/96qzsbwo/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no space right there, i even try to return the result to browser console, but still no result (by that i mean returning the `matched` to browser)

Also i just tried to console.log both again 

`0: 58058dcf42d75a150d8c0c18
 1: 58058dcf42d75a150d8c0c18`

Comment: I added full console.log (item and data(reply[i].data)) http://pastebin.com/xS7ZCcap

Comment: Can you check the type of `item._id` and the `reply[i].data[j].ref`?

Comment: Also, I have never used the `async` module, but have you confirmed that the `arr` array and `results` array are traversed correspondingly?

Comment: @VivekPradhan Both are object, and yes i'm pretty sure they're

Comment: So making them string seems to be working

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was going to suggest. A basic `.toString()` might have helped. :)

Comment: @Raga, just so you know `==` never works for objects.